# How to create dynamic dropdownlist with datasource from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I trying to create dynamic dropdownlist with datasource from my access database. I want to add the dropdownlist into a table. Tried to do like this but it didn't work. How can I do it, and get the value if a item selected in dropdownlist? Thank you.

```
DropDownList mylist = new DropDownList();
            mylist.DataSource = DBConnectivity.getMovieSchedule(c.Movie_ID);
            mylist.DataTextField = "date";
            mylist.DataValueField = "id";
            mylist.DataBind();
            c6.Controls.Add(mylist);
```

Comment: What does not work? Is the list empty, does it crash?

Comment: the list doesnot show anything.

Comment: So your list is probably empty, there is debug you can check it.

Comment: Show the result of calling `DBConnectivity.getMovieSchedule(c.Movie_ID)`

Comment: now there is item in the list. How can I get the selected value?

Comment: Every time you select an item in the list the OnSelectedIndexChanged event is triggered. Assign an event handler to this event and you can acquire the text value (I suppose this is what you want) via the SelectedValue property of the control.

Here you can check how to assing the handler:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.onselectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Here some info for the SelectedValue property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connstring"))
{
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM YourTable", sqlConnection);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(sqlReader["name"].ToString());
    }

    sqlReader.Close();
}
```